# How to use useEffect in Preact?

Tags: javascript, preact

I came across posts where people mention `useEffect` and even give some great examples, but I cannot find any real documentation. Also I grepped `node_modules/preact` dir and there is no mention of `useEffect` in the entire code base. Is this a separate module? Or I got the wrong version of preact (8.4.2)? Please explain and give a complete working example.

Comment: Hooks were released as part of `React 16.8`. Preact hooks are in beta. https://github.com/preactjs/preact/pull/1302.

Comment: The preact site says its is comparable to react 15.x but useffect looks like its react 16 https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

useEffect is primarily about accessing the [Lifecycle Methods](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/components#lifecycle-methods) in a FunctionalComponent.

Preact ClassComponents have direct access to the [Lifecycle methods](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/components#lifecycle-methods), but [FunctionalComponents](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/components#functional-components) do not.

Therefore, `useEffect()` acts as all the Lifecycle Methods rolled into one.

For example: <sub>*(Full example using Preact/Typescript)*</sub>

**In a ClassComponent** you can load data via the `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import * as style from './style.scss';
import { get } from '../../../utils/ajax';
import { ExampleDataObject } from '../types';

interface ComponentNameProps {
  id: number;
}

interface ComponentNameState {
  data: ExampleDataObject;
}

export class ComponentName extends Component<ComponentNameProps, ComponentNameState> {
  public render ({ id }: ComponentNameProps, { data }: ComponentNameState) {
     return (
        <div class={style.container}>
          {JSON.stringify(data)}
        </div>
     );
  }
  public componentDidMount(): void {
     get(`/getData?id=${id}`).then((d) => {
        this.setState({ data: d });
     });
  }
}
```

**In a FunctionalComponent**, the same effect can be achieved thus:

```
import { h, FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';
import * as style from './style.scss';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';
import { get } from '../../../utils/ajax';
import { ExampleDataObject } from '../types';

interface ExampleProps {
  id: number;
}

export const Example: FunctionalComponent<ExampleProps> = ({id}) => {
const [data, setData] = useState<ExampleDataObject | undefined>;
useEffect(() => {
  get<ExampleDataObject>(`/getData?id=${id}`)
     .then((d) => {
        setData(d);
     });
}, [id]);

     return (
        <div class={style.ExampleWrapper}>
          {data !== undefined && (
             JSON.stringify(data)
          )};
        </div>
     );
}
```

**Reminder:** (for those using VSCode - which should be *everyone-in-the-know*):
VSCode will often do the import lines for you *(i.e. using the Quick Fix helper)* - but it often gets the import line wrong for useState / useEffect (it will add /src to the end, which doesn't work). So remember to double-check imports for these two.

WRONG:
    `import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks/src';`

CORRECT:
    `import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';`

Answer (score 11):

Hooks were released as part of `React 16.8`. Preact hooks are in [beta](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/pull/1302.) as of version 10. You can get access to them by updating Preact to the latest beta with `npm install preact@10.0.0-beta.2`

Usage,

```
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks'

export function Demo(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c+1)}>{count}</button>
}
```